# I need to insert a large string in between two pattern using shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, dash-shell

I have an HTML file in that I have a comment line as:

```
<!-- tag1 --><!-- tag11 -->
```

I need to insert a `JQ` file element in between them.

I have tried and I was able to insert a small string but my string is large in size. Can anyone suggest me an idea?

```
i=0
code="(jq -r '.["$i"].code' file.json)"; 
eval v=\$$code; 
sed -i 's/(<!-- tag1 -->)\(<!-- tag11 -->)/\1'$v'\2/' index.html;
```

It threw me an error as:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unterminated `s' command
```

However:

```
v="xxxxxxx" 
sed -i 's/(<!-- tag1 -->)\(<!-- tag11 -->)/\1'$v'\2/' index.html;
```

The string is inserted perfectly can anyone help?

Comment: Probably `$v` contains a slash `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ramruma](https://serverfault.com/a/549351/393191), you could try putting the long string in file and then use file contents insertion, as follows:

```
sed -i "/teststring/r file1.txt" index.html
```

From [sed manual](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) `r` flag is used for reading file contents.